# How to setup a custom domain on dotcloud?

Tags: dotcloud

According to the docs on dotcloud, I have "dotcloud alias add  ramen.www www.example.com" executed.Then I got "please add the following dns record:  www.example.com IN CNAME gateway.dotcloud.com". I have no idea what that means. What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

You should configure your DNS domain "example.com" so that "www.example.com" is a CNAME (a kind of symbolic link, in DNS parlance) to gateway.dotcloud.com.

Since you are asking this question, I suppose you are not running your own DNS servers (else you probably would know all the arcanes required to setup this famous CNAME); so your DNS are probably hosted by your registrar (the place where you bought the domain name in the first place). In that case, the registrar very probably offers a web interface allowing to setup this CNAME for you.

Don't hesitate to be more specific and tell which registrar (or even, which domain) you are using, so we can give more details!

Comment: Actually,it isn't because I hesitate, it's because I dont have one.According to what you said, I guess I'll have to get a DNS server or what you called "registrar".Thank you.